# How can we use include function in html

Tags: html

How can I include one html file in another html file?

Comment: What did you try? What are you trying to do. Please include more details.

Comment: Bad question, but my answer is this. _Please don't._

Comment: @Truth Well, looks like he's trying to use include() in an html file..

Comment: Hi Damien yes you right i am trying to use include function in html file.

Comment: Rahul, include is a **php** function. You **need** php if you want to use it. HTML is **not** a programming language, it's a markup language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot include one HTML file in another directly in HTML. You should use a server side script (like PHP) to include, or JavaScript to load it in a div.

Comment: `You cannot include one HTML file in another directly in HTML.` - this should be qualified as "*with PHP*". [You *can* do it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) if the server supports it...

Comment: agree but he wants to 'include one html file in another html' and nothing about a 'php into another php'

Comment: And besides, you _can_. `<!--#include virtual="file.html" -->`.

Comment: hi mugur,u r right.i dont want to use php in to another php.i wnat to include one html file in another html.

Comment: then you can use the solution that @Mr.Disappointment suggested

Comment: Rahul, you've tagged your question with `php`...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your HTML has a .php extension, you simply do:

```
<html>
<body>
    Your <i>HTML</i>
<? include("somefile.html"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

However:

1. Your original file needs a php extension so that it is interpreted as a php file
2. The file you want to include (`somefile.html`) cannot have any `html`, `head` or `body` tags.

Comment: Hi,without using php tags how can i include an html file in another html page.

Comment: As Mr. Dissapointment suggested, you can use `<!--#include virtual="somefile.html" -->` if your server support this. You can read more about it [here](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/include.html).

Answer (score 0):

With use of a preprocessor such as PHP, you can include the source of a file (this could be your html file) in another. For example...

```
<!-- file.html -->
<table><tBody>
  <tr><td>Cell 1 Row 1</td><td>Cell 2 Row 1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Cell 3 Row 2</td><td>Cell 4 Row 2</td></tr>
</tBody></table>
```

Above is file.html. If you wish to include this in your PHP, use the following:

```
<?php
  echo "<html><body>";
  echo "Below is an example of a table in HTML.";
  include('./file.html');  // Keep the location relative to current_dir
  echo "Goodbye...";
  echo "</body></html>";
?>
```

The above example works, however is a bit hackish. A more ideal answer to solve this problem would be to use PHP's file functions to read the file then print the contents, as below. We will use file.html again as an example.

```
<?php
  echo "<html><body>";
  echo "Below is an example of a table in HTML.";

  $fp = fopen("./file.html", 'r');           // Open the file for reading
  echo fread($fp, filesize("./file.html"));  // Read whole file
  fclose($fp);

  echo "Goodbye...";
  echo "</body></html>";
?>
```

The above two PHP examples do exactly the same thing. The second takes 1.914236706689373 seconds longer (according to PHP's microtime function).

Comment: hi shane,i have two html files and i want to include one html in another html page.Is this possible??

Comment: rahul, read the other answers and comments.

Comment: If you do not have access to a preprossessor on the server, then your only alternative is to use javascript which will include the file after the page has loaded - would this alternative suffice?

To begin with, when the page is sent to the client, it will not have the included file. Then the javascript will be run to include the second file.